# Image upload button Not work on android Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, image-uploading, android-browser

This code work fine on Google chrome but not work on android browser
this is my link:

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/newmobile/icnUploadImage.gif",'',array('width'=>'55','style'=>'padding: 0 15px;')), '#', array('style' => 'right: 0.2%', 'class' => 'add_photo_btn', 'onclick' => '$("#MobileLandingPost_image_name").click(); return false;'));
```

and this is my script ...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isFileInputSupported = (function () {
        // Handle devices which falsely report support
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android (1.0|1.1|1.5|1.6|2.0|2.1))|(Windows Phone (OS 7|8.0))|(XBLWP)|(ZuneWP)|(w(eb)?OSBrowser)|(webOS)|(Kindle\/(1.0|2.0|2.5|3.0))/)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    if(typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined' || !isFileInputSupported()) {
        $('#imageupload').remove();
    } else {
        $('#MobileLandingPost_image_name').change(function(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files;
            var f = files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    $('.add_photo_btn').html(['<img src="', e.target.result,'" title="', theFile.name, '" style="padding: 0 15px;" width="75" height="67" />'].join(''));
                };
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.add_photo_btn').html('<img src="'+ e.target.result+'" title="'+ theFile.name + '" style="padding: 0 15px;" width="75" height="67" />');
```